# Encode a dataframe after in import in sql

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I have imported a table with pandas `read_frame`.

My `DataFrame` has special characters like é , à and so on. When i want to display it i have strange characters.

I wold like to know what can i do to encode my html output :

```
import pandas 
import pandas.io.sql
from IPython.display import HTML

df = pandas.io.sql.read_frame('a valid sql query') 
HTML(df.to_html())
```

I need to use the HTML output to display all the columns ( i have 90 columns) 
and this is the encoding that works, `'cp1252'`, when i import in to csv

post edited :

I wanted to edit my post with an image but i need 10 reputation to do so ... In fact i didn't put any enconding in my connection . Is it possible with sql.read_frame ? I used a pyodbc :

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=PRD;UID=***;PWD=***;QUIETMODE=YES;')

df = pandas.io.sql.read_frame("""select  * from *""", cnxn )
```

Comment: Can you show a picture or link to a notebook that doesn't work? I can't reproduce this in the IPython notebook.

Comment: How did you connect to the database? What encoding did you specified when you created the connection object. Can you add that part of the code to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding to your connection creation the next thing:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=PRD;UID=*;PWD=*;QUIETMODE=YES;',
                       unicode_results=True)
```

That should make sure that all the strings returned from your connections are unicode. The rest will be handled by pandas and IPython Notebook.